# Django not updating Database

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django 1.10 project with python 3.
This is my models.py:

```
# /Multiple choices/
SEX_CHOICES = (('M', 'Male'),
               ('F', 'Female')
              )

ZONE_CHOICES = (('D', 'Départementale'),
               ('N', 'Nationale')
              )

# /Extension of User model/
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')  
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, default='M')
    departementNumber = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=88, validators=[MaxValueValidator(101)])
    departement = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zone = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ZONE_CHOICES, default='D')
    receivedApprove = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    receivedDescription = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    receivedDesapprove = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    givenApprove = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    givenDescription = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    givenDisapprove = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

What I am trying to do is to take some users information and complete their profile. Here is what i did  in my views.py :

```
user_id = request.user

firstname = form.cleaned_data['firstname']
lastname = form.cleaned_data['lastname']
email = form.cleaned_data['email']
sex = form2.cleaned_data['sex']
departementNumber = form2.cleaned_data['departementNumber']
zone = form2.cleaned_data['zone']
```

At this stage, everything is working fine. The problem start when I try to update my model. User object is updating correctly :

```
upd = User.objects.filter(id=user_id.id).update(first_name=firstname, last_name=lastname, email=email)
```

But Profile is not updating :

```
upd2 = Profile.objects.filter(id=user_id.id).update(sex=sex, departementNumber=departementNumber, departement=depName, zone=zone)
```

And I have not a single warning or error message.

Comment: Firstly, why are you using `update` to update a single row? And secondly, why do you assume that a Profile has the same id value as its related User?

Comment: Well because in queryset  `update` is the proper way to update a model. And " why do you assume that a Profile has the same id value as its related User?" Since I am using `OneToOneField`, Profile should use User id as a foreign key. No ?

Comment: Yes but you're not querying by foreign key, you're querying by primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in `Profile` model. You should add `primary_key=True` to `user` field, in order to get the same id as the actual User.

e.g.

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add another situation in which the database does not update when using the update() method.

```
order = Order.objects.filter(id=d['id']).first()

Order.objects.filter(id=d['id']).update(currency=d['currency'])

# further code using order
```

In this situation the order row is referenced in the first line of code and the update() in line 2 does not work. I don't know the internal reason why line 2 does not update the row in the DB, but from a logical standpoint one should anyway put line 1 after line 2 (which solves it). However if making several code changes this can occur and it looks at first unintuitive why the update() returns '1' even though no update of the DB row happened.