# Update into existing database not working

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a page where the users can add a new mco number, when the user click on the Add mco button, it will retrieve the id as shown below:

[image]

but when the user add the new mco number and click on the submit button, it will create another row and not update into the id database as shown below, why is that so and how do I solve this issue?

[image]

views.py

```
@login_required()
def AddMCO(request, id):
    photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":

        form = AddMCOForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            mcoNum = form.cleaned_data['mcoNum']
            form.save()

            return redirect('ViewMCO')

    else:
        form = AddMCOForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "photo": photo

    }
   
    return render(request, 'AddMCO.html', context, )
```

forms.py

```
class AddMCOForm(forms.ModelForm):

    mcoNum = forms.CharField(
        label='Enter MCO Number',
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Please enter MCO Number here..'
            }
        )
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ("mcoNum",)


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddMCOForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['mcoNum'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'MCO Number'})
        self.fields['mcoNum'].label = ''
        self.fields['mcoNum'].help_text = ''
```

AddMCO.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
      });
    </script>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>SCS Add MCO</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Moment.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-VBLiveTKyUZMEzJd6z2mhfxIqz3ZATCuVMawPZGzIfA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Tempus Dominus Bootstrap 4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" integrity="sha256-XPTBwC3SBoWHSmKasAk01c08M6sIA5gF5+sRxqak2Qs=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js" integrity="sha256-z0oKYg6xiLq3yJGsp/LsY9XykbweQlHl42jHv2XTBz4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body class="m-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3>Add MCO Number</h3>

                <a href="{% url 'ViewMCO' %}" class="btn btn-dark my-3">Go Back</a>
                <div class="card" style="width: 400px">


                     <form  method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                        <div class="form-group m-3">

                            <br>
                            {{ form.as_p}}
                        </div>





                        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary m-3">Submit</button>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

models.py

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    STEP1 = "Reception"
    STEP2 = "Launching"

    STATUS = (
        (STEP1, 'Reception'),
        (STEP2, 'Launching'),

    )

    Datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    mcoNum = models.TextField() #mcoNum stand for MCO number
    serialno = models.TextField()  # serialno stand for serial number
    partno = models.TextField()  # partno stand for part number
    reception = models.TextField()
    Customername = models.TextField() #Custoner Name
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS, default=STEP1, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reception
```

Comment: Can you add the Photo model? Is the purpose of the view to update/change the "mcoNum" field of an existing Photo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can we use modelform to update an existing instance of a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801805/can-we-use-modelform-to-update-an-existing-instance-of-a-model)

Comment: sure, i will update it with the model

Comment: hi, i have updated my model

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Hi, the current one you send me does not work, yes mine did save into the database, but it is not save with the id that is retrieve, for example I retrieve id 3 which is the data with reception number 234 and i enter a new mco number, the mco number should update into id 3 and not create a new row with no reception nmuber, part number etc

Comment: Did you read the answers on the linked question properly? The top voted answer says: "_A subclass of ModelForm can accept an existing model instance as the keyword argument instance; if this is supplied, save() will update that instance._"... Please _read_ the answers on the linked question carefully before saying "_it does not work_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not passing the instance to the form assuming the photo model has addMCO Form as model form of course.

```
@login_required()
def AddMCO(request, id):
    photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":

        form = AddMCOForm(request.POST, instance=photo)
        if form.is_valid():
            mcoNum = form.cleaned_data['mcoNum']
            form.save()

            return redirect('ViewMCO')

    else:
        form = AddMCOForm(instance=photo)
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "photo": photo

    }


return render(request, 'AddMCO.html', context, )
```

Comment: I have another question, do you mind helping me?

Comment: So when the users add the mco number, the status should change to launching and timing should change to the time that it is edited, how do i do it?

Comment: You can set a the status when handling the creating a new mco number in your view and for the time edited add a updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_add=true) and get that each time an instance is created. hope that make sens.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned Django version and which db is used.

Check if this can help you. [Django not updating database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147931/django-not-updating-database)

Comment: i use sqlite 3 and django 2.2.20